# Angularjs Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Hi folks i am using Angular JS & Kendo UI in my application. I am getting a strange error which i am unable to get around. i.e. **TypeError: object is not a function**

```
TypeError: Function expected
at Anonymous function (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:3745:29)
at Anonymous function (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:3828:22)
at Anonymous function (.../app/js/directives/angular-kendo.js:142:21)
at invoke (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:2795:18)
at instantiate (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:2805:7)
at Anonymous function (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:4621:7)
at Anonymous function (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:4198:13)
at forEach (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:117:11)
at nodeLinkFn (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:4185:11)
at compositeLinkFn (.../app/lib/angular/angular.js:3823:14)
```

While i did some research online i found this to be an issue when the order of the script files in the html file are not proper. Hence, i added this in the following order.

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/angular-kendo.js"></script>
```

Am i missing anything? Has it anything to do with the version of Angular/jQuery? I am using jQuery 1.8.2. Also angular-kendo.js for "kendo.directives".

Please suggest.

Comment: What versions of AngularJS, Kendo and Angular-Kendo?

Comment: i am not sure about Angular-Kendo but i am using 1.2.9 of Angular. I posted the error in detail in the question for more information.

Comment: try it with AngularJS v1.0.5 to see if the error is version specific

Comment: Please check below link. http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/
If possible then please use Jquery 1.9.* version and check your issue.

Comment: Guys thanks a ton for all your suggestions/help. It works now. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Angular v1.0.5 & jQuery 1.9 and above (though i used 1.11.1)

Have the scripts in proper order as below :

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/angular-kendo.js"></script>
```

Thanks a ton @ Lars Hoppner & @jayesh Goyani for your quick help and valid inputs.